# Free Ajax Framework for ASP.Net Easy to use and code

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I would like to know is there any Free Ajax Framework other than AjaxPro and Microsoft Ajax Framework for ASP.Net 2.0. The feature that I am looking for is ease of use as provided by Microsoft Ajax Framework and speed as provided by AjaxPro.

Answer (score 2):

If by "Ajax framework" you mean "JavaScript Framework", I'm going to state the obvious and say [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). They've also [received Microsoft's blessing lately](http://www.microsoft.com/web/content.aspx?id=microsoft-adopts-open-source-jQuery-JavaScript-library).

There are a dozen other free ones available as well. I can think of only one that you'd have to pay for.